# Ansible jenkins_job add header information for Jenkins-Crumb

Tags: ansible

I like to use Jenkins Job module to create the job. Jenkins required to pass `Jenkins-Crumb` part of API call. Is it possible to add Head information part of `jenkins_jobs` module?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/jenkins_job_module.html

Thanks

Comment: Based on the code and doc, you cannot do this in the current Ansible module. It is part of the `POST` headers, and you would need to PR this functionality.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks. May I know the process to open the pull request for this module

Comment: Source code and repo is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/web_infrastructure/jenkins_job_info.py

Comment: Even i'm looking for the solution since unable to create a job inside the folder using jenkins_jobs module

Comment: @user10912187 your better of using https://github.com/cdancy/jenkins-rest this works with crumb.